# Portability Analyzer Visual Studio 2022/2019 .Net 6

Tags: migration, .net-6.0, .net-standard-2.0

I know that, officially, Portability Analyzer does not support Visual Studio 2022.

1. But is it possible to somehow get an analysis of the migration from .Net Framework to .Net 6?
2. Is it possible somehow in the Visual Studio 2019 to get a portability analysis of the .net 6?
3. Will it be enough that porting to .Net 6 will have the same compatibility as .net 5 or .Net Standart 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can use upgrade-assistant itself to analyze as Portability Analyzer does not support in Visual Studio 2022:

Usage:
upgrade-assistant analyze [options]

Please find below the resources for more details your kind reference:

https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant#analyze-solution-prior-to-upgrade
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/the-net-upgrade-assistant-analyze-command-output-s-1/1657318